# Wireless internet not working with two devices simultaneously

Tags: networking, router

I have a Linksys WRT54GS2 router, a PC (Windows XP) and a laptop (Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit).

I have been using this router for 3 months. I was able to use the internet on both devices simultaneously until now. But suddenly since yesterday it only works for one device at a time, not both.

If I connect to the router then I can access the internet only from the laptop. To use the internet from the PC, I have to power off the router, type in run "netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt", and restart the PC. But as the router is off, the internet is inaccessible on the laptop.

While router is on, the PC shows limited or no connectivity.

I tried reseting the router 2-3 times.

On the laptop it sometimes shows "IP address conflict has been detected", even though the IP addresses of the devices were not the same. The IP address of the PC shows 169.X.X.X (when the router is on), whereas the ISP's IP addresses start with 124.X.X.X.

I tried making the PC's IP address static. It shows the LAN symbol as connected, but still the internet cannot be accessed.

I am not even able to view the router's configuration. None of the addresses 192.168.1.0 , 192.168.1.1, 192.168.0.1, or 192.168.0.0 work.

Is there anything I have to change in my configuration to be able to use the internet on both devices? (I have not make any changes in configuration in the last 3 months.)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to connect to your router and double check that the DHCP settings are turned on. Your safest choice is to connect one of the laptops using a network cable(make sure the LAN card is set to DHCP) if that doesn't work manually assign an IP address to the LAN card. If all else fails factory reset you modem and revert everything back to DHCP on your network cards and try again. If that still doesn't work your router could be toast.

If you are using WIFI make sure the SSID and password(And password security(WEP, WPA and WPA2)) is correct when connecting as this can also cause the same problems.

Once you're in the router check your LAN setting to ensure the DHCP functionality is on.

The DHCP server settings is where you specific 192.168.x.x. ip range, and these are the addresses that get assigned when your laptops will request them, and don't forget to save your settings before you exit. All it takes it one unplanned reboot to wipe your device back to the default settings or the last known save.

The reason you are getting a 169.x.x.x number is because the laptop can't find the DHCPserver a.k.a the router.